# ggplot in R with fortify takes too long to process small geospatial data

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, geospatial

I am trying to use ggplot to draw a map of Canada and to colour code each region based on total sales. The geospatial file is from GADM and contains only 12 provinces (level 1). When I fortify the data the resulting data.frame is over 4 million rows. When when I try to draw the map with ggplot it seems to hang. I've left it for 30 minutes and had to give up.

Is the problem the size of the result of fortify? I don't know how to reduce the size. I've tried playing with the 'region' argument in fortify but that causes fortify to appear to hang.

I have included all my code and the URL to download the data I am working with.

```
require(dplyr)

# loaded from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Technology-Hatchery/Rcode/master/Data/Sample%20-%20Superstore%20Sales%20(Excel).csv
orders <- read.csv(file='Data/Orders.csv', sep=',', header=TRUE, na.strings = '')
orders$Order.Date <- as.Date(orders$Order.Date, '%m/%d/%y')
orders$Order.Priority <- as.factor(orders$Order.Priority)
orders$Customer.Name <- as.character(orders$Customer.Name)
orders$Ship.Date <- as.Date(orders$Ship.Date, '%m/%d/%y')
orders$Order.Total <- orders$Unit.Price * orders$Order.Quantity
orders <- tbl_df(orders)

require(raster)
require(ggplot2)
require(RColorBrewer)
require(rgdal)
require(rgeos)

# map from GADM: http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.7/rds/CAN_adm1.rds
canada <- readRDS('../../Geo/GADM/Canada/CAN_adm1.rds')
canada <- spTransform(canada, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

# Add my data to spatial polygon data.frame
canada.df <- fortify(canada)
summary(canada.df)

nrow(canada.df)

# [1] 4005898

# Build region list and add to spatial DF
provinces <- canada@data %>% dplyr::select(OBJECTID, NAME_1) %>% dplyr::rename(id = OBJECTID, Province = NAME_1)
head(provinces)

# Add total sales to spatial DF
provinceOrders <- orders %>% mutate(Province = as.character(Province)) %>%
       left_join(., provinces, by='Province') %>%
       group_by(id, Province) %>%
       dplyr::summarise(Total = sum(Order.Total)) %>%
       dplyr::select(id, Total)
head(provinceOrders)

canada.df <- merge(canada.df, provinceOrders, by='id', all.x=TRUE)
canada.df <- arrange(canada.df, order, group)
head(canada.df)

ggplot() +
geom_polygon(data=canada.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=Total), color='white') +
scale_fill_gradient(high='Red', low= 'Blue')
#geom_text(aes(label=Province, x=long, y=lat))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this shapefile from NOAA instead. It has all the provinces but doesn't have the super-precise coastline polygons (which aren't needed):

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

url <- "http://www.nws.noaa.gov/geodata/catalog/national/data/province.zip"
fil <- basename(url)
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(url, fil)
fils <- grep("shp", unzip(fil), ignore.case=TRUE, value=TRUE)
ca <- readOGR(fils, ogrListLayers(fils)[1])

ca_map <- fortify(ca, region="NAME")

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=ca_map, map=ca_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="black", fill="white", size=0.15)
gg <- gg + coord_map("lambert", 44, 85)
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

A `system.time(ca_map <- fortify(ca, region="NAME"))` shows:

```
##    user  system elapsed 
##   0.517   0.005   0.523
```

pretty consistently for me.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

It's true that `ggplot` is slow with large data.frames, but when I download your .rds file and run your code, `fortify(...)` takes a few seconds, and plotting the map takes about 2 min.

You can also grab the spatialPolygonsDataFrame directly using `getData(...)` in the `raster` package, although oddly this file is half the size of yours (50MB). This file plots in about 1 min., and half of that is converting to the lambert projection (remove the `coord_map(...)` call and it takes ~ 25 sec.)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)   # for getData()

canada <- getData("GADM", country="CAN", level=1)
canada.df <- fortify(canada)
system.time(
  plot(ggplot()+
         geom_polygon(data=canada.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
                      fill="lightblue",color="grey20", size=0.15)+
         coord_map(projection="lambert", 44, 85))
)
#    user  system elapsed 
#   46.75    2.76   49.72
```

[image]

Either way, `ggplot` certainly doesn't hang.

If you could provide your `orders.csv` file it might be possible to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. When I used the file provided from hrbrmstr my script ran in just a few seconds including fortify and ggplot. So the code for processing orders should be fine.